# Computing the ideal of all 0-valued multivariate polynomials over a field $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

I'm just looking for some direction here (researching an open problem from: [survey](https://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/ChenKaWi2011.pdf), namely equivalence of polynomials upto change of basis).

Define the set of zero-valued polynomials in $k[X_1, \cdots, X_n]$ to be all polynomials $f$ such that $f(k^n) = 0$ or $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in k^n$.  So for instance if $k = \Bbb{F}_2$ then $X^2 + X$ is one such polynomial. The set of all such polynomials clearly forms an ideal of $k[X_1, \cdots, X_n]$ which must be finitely generated by Hilbert's basis theorem (every field being Noetherian vacuously).

The end goal is compare two polynomials $f, g$ by value (not by formal standard form equivalence).  So $f \equiv g \iff f - g \in I$ the ideal in the first paragraph, or alternatively $\overline{f} = \overline{g} \pmod I$, either of which are amenable to Grobner basis techniques.

Question: How do I compute $I$ for any field $k$ assuming I have a representation for $k$'s arithmetic on a computer?  Can we say that if $k = \Bbb{Q}$, then $I = (0)$?

Comment: The last question is easy by using rationals are infinite.

Comment: @Mohan could you outline that argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an infinite field the kernel is trivial. Proof : because univariate polynomials have finitely many roots, if $f\ne 0\in k[Y,t],Y=(y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1})$ and its coefficient of $Y^s t^m$ is non-zero, then there is some $a_n\in k$ such that the coefficient of $Y^s $ of $f(Y,a_n)$ is non-zero, ie. it is not the zero polynomial, repeating $n$ times we obtain some $a\in k^n$ such that $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\ne 0$.

For a finite field the kernel of the evaluation map $$e:\Bbb{F}_q[X_1,\ldots,X_n] \to (\text{the set of functions }(\Bbb{F}_q)^n\to \Bbb{F}_q)$$
is the ideal $$(X_1^q-X_1,\ldots,X_n^q-X_n)\subset \Bbb{F}_q[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$$

Proof : because $\prod_{m=1}^n ((X_m-a_m)^{q-1}-1)$ is non-zero only at $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, we get that $e$ is surjective, thus as a $\Bbb{F}_q$-vector space $\Bbb{F}_q[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/\ker(e)$ is of dimension $q^n$.

On the other hand it is clear that $(X_1^q-X_1,\ldots,X_n^q-X_n)$ is in $\ker(e)$ and 
as a $\Bbb{F}_q$-vector space 
$$\Bbb{F}_q[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1^q-X_1,\ldots,X_n^q-X_n)$$ is of dimension $q^n$ (since in the quotient, only powers  $<q$ of the $X_j$ appear).

Comment: I'm not understanding why the evaluation is into $\Bbb{F}_q^{q^n}$ instead of just $\Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: We evaluate at all the points not only one

Comment: Still not clicking.  $f \in k[X,Y], f(X, Y) = X^2Y - 3 \implies f(x,y) \in k$ for $x,y \in k^2$.

Comment: We send a polynomial to a function $k^n\to k$. When $k$ is a finite field it is $k^N,N=|k|^n$.

Comment: why wouldn't taking a kernel work with the usual eval map?

Comment: I think your argument is overcomplicated and leaves out the important information.  I hate proofs such as that, personally.

Comment: ? What is complicated to you ? And I'm quite sure there is no simpler proof.

Comment: I'm not understanding your surjectivity argument.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why we can't use an evaluation map $x \mapsto f(x) \in \Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Also, how did you come up with the expression $X_i^q - X_i$ that is used every where?

Comment: $t^q-t=\prod_{a\in \Bbb{F}_q} (t-a)$ it is the smallest degree polynomial vanishing on $\Bbb{F}_q$. The evaluation map is $e$, it evaluates the polynomial at every $x$, not only one, it sends the polynomial $f$ to the function $x\to f(x)$... For example with $f(t)=t^2\in \Bbb{F}_3[t]$ then $e(f) = (0,1^2,2^2)=(0,1,1)$. This is what we need to find which polynomials vanish on $(\Bbb{F}_q)^n$.

Comment: The surjectivity is saying that every function $F:(\Bbb{F}_q)^n\to \Bbb{F}_q$ can be represented as a $n$-variable polynomial, namely $\sum_{a\in (\Bbb{F}_q)^n} F(a) P(X-a)$ where $P(X)=\prod_{m=1}^n (1-X_m^{q-1})$